# ListActivity or AppCompatActivity for displaying a list?

Tags: android, list, android-appcompat

since I have not programmed for Android for some years now I just started again and have a question:

Whats the state of the art to display a List? In the past it was the ListActivity. But nowerdays I saw that there is a new AppCompatActivity to support the action bar.

So what sould I use to make it the modern way?

Comment: RecyclerView is the new ListView

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity :) Declare a listView in your activity.xml. In your onCreateView get the reference to listView using findViewById and then declare an adapter, set the adapter to listView. That should do :) Yeah tim-castelijns is absolutely correct RecyclerView is the latest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago, in legacy applications, you could use `ListActivity` or `ListView` inside regular `Activity`. In the newest versions of Android, preferred way of displaying items on a list is using so called [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). Please, see linked documentation. It's quite good and helpful. Besides naming convetion, `RecyclerView` gives you more flexibility and has *ViewHolder* pattern implemented out-of-the-box for re-using views during the scrolling what increases application's performance. Before introducing `RecyclerView`, you had to implement *ViewHolder* pattern on your own.

To sum up:

Instead of `Activity` or `ListActivity`, you should use `AppCompatActivity` and place `RecyclerView` inside it to keep backward compatibility with older systems and devices.

Answer (score 3):

You should totally go for AppCompatActivity and use RecyclerView. It gives you a whole lot of new features and automatically improves the performance compared to a listView. You can take a deeper look in here http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

ListView is still a valid solution if you do not need animation.

Just don't forget about viewholder pattern.